# Can future value by computer as a finite geometric series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This question asks

A student invests $200 at the start of each month for 24 months, starting today. If the investment yields 0.5% per month, compounded monthly, what is the future value of the investment two years from today?

Per the formula for a finite geometric sum, my answer is:
[image]

a= 200
r = 1.005
k = 24
Which is being marked as incorrect.

Comment: Isn't this accounted for by the exponentiation in the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A student invests $200 at the start of each month for 24 months,
>   **starting today.**

You used the formula which calculates the future value where the first payment is made after one month. You have to multiply your expression by 1.005 to get the right result:

$C_{24}=200\cdot 1.005\cdot \frac{1.005^{24}-1}{1.005-1}=5111.82$